# Is there much critical analysis of "The Hunger Angel"?

Tags: german-language, herta-muller, the-hunger-angel

Herta Müller, the Romanian-born-German-novelist, won the 2009 Nobel Prize in Literature. In the same year, her novel *The Hunger Angel* (*Atemschaukel*) was published and received much laudation. Despite this, it seems to me that there has been a dearth of critical analysis of this novel (at least in English, I concede that I do not possess the ability to find it in any other language, although I would easily believe it exists in German).

So far I have only been able to find three or so essays/articles on the book (as well as some reviews by newspapers) but nothing that seemed to me to be serious, academic criticism. This was a huge surprise to me given the fact that the book came out in the same year that she won the Nobel Prize. My question is: has much academic criticism been written concerning this novel? Is there any substantial analysis of her work as a writer that pays special attention to this novel?

Comment: Is there any particular aspect of this work you're looking for criticism on? Also, I created the book and author tags, but I'm not so sure about the others.

Comment: Relevant meta post: https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/753/481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

Academic articles specifically about this book, in both English and German:

- Beate Petra Kory, "Herta Müllers Sprachpantomime *Atemschaukel* Ein Annäherungsversuch an die Zentralmetapher des Romans", *Temeswarer Beiträge zur Germanistik, Band 10* (2013), pp. 59-67. German title translates to "Herta Müller's language pantomime [?] *Atemschaukel*: an approach to the central metaphor of the novel". [Available here.](https://litere.uvt.ro/publicatii/TBG/pdf/TBG/tbg-10-2013.06121301.pdf#page=60)
- Pavlo Shopin, "Unpacking the Suitcases: Autofiction and Metaphor in Herta Müller’s *Atemschaukel*", *Seminar: A Journal of Germanic Studies* (2014), 50(2), pp. 197-215. [Available here.](http://www.utpjournals.press/doi/full/10.3138/sem.50.2.197)
- Bettina Bannasch, "Zero – A Gaping Mouth: The Discourse of the Camps in Herta Müller’s Atemschaukel between Literary Theory and Political Philosophy", chapter in *Other people's pain: narratives of trauma and the question of ethics* (2011), edited by Martin Modlinger and Philipp Sonntag.
- Olivia Spiridon, "From Fact to Fiction: Herta Müller’s Atemschaukel", chapter 8 in *Herta Müller: Politics and Aesthetics* (2013), edited by Bettina Brandt and Valentina Glajar.
- Christian Bergmann, "Das Unsagbare sagen: Metapher, Symbol und Allegorie in Herta Müllers Roman Atemschaukel", *Muttersprache: Zeitschrift zur Pflege und Erforschung der deutschen Sprache* (2011), 121(3), pp. 220-226. German title translates to "Speak the unspeakable: metaphor, symbol, and allegory in Herta Müller’s novel Atemschaukel".

More general analysis that pays special attention to this novel:

- Karin Bauer, "Gender and the Sexual Politics of Exchange in Herta Müller’s Prose", chapter 10 in *Herta Müller* (2013), edited by Brigid Haines and Lyn Marven.
- Gunther Martens & Benjamin Biebuyck, "Channelling figurativity through narrative: The paranarrative in fiction and non-fiction", *Language and Literature* (2013), 22(3), pp. 249-262. Contains a section entitled "Paranarrative and metaphor *in praesentia* in Herta Müller's *The Hunger Angel* (2009)".

More articles specifically about this novel (in German), though I'm not sure how academic they are, can be found in the 10/2011 edition of *Gegenwartsliteratur: Ein germanistisches Jahrbuch (A German Studies Yearbook)*, focusing on Herta Müller ([see here](http://www.stauffenburg.de/asp/books.asp?id=1188)):

- Hartmut Steinecke, "Herta Müller: *Atemschaukel*. Ein Roman vom “Nullpunkt der Existenz”". German title translates to "Herta Müller: *The Hunger Angel*. A novel from the "origin of existence"".
- Michael Braun, "Die Erfindung der Erinnerung: Herta Müllers *Atemschaukel*". German title translates to "The invention of memory: Herta Müller's *Atemschaukel*".
- Norbert Otto Eke, "“Gelber Mais, keine Zeit”. Herta Müllers Nach-Schrift *Atemschaukel*. Roman". German title translates to ""Yellow corn, no time". Herta Müller's post-script novel [?] *Atemschaukel*".

---

How did I find all this?

### Using Google Scholar!

It took a surprisingly short time to gather all the material presented here. The most time-consuming part was just to write up all of these references in a proper style and translate the German ones. Getting a list of them was pretty easy just from [here](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=%22the+hunger+angel%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) and [here](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=Atemschaukel&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5). I only started using Google Scholar recently, but it's an **invaluable** tool for finding academic references in literature and other subjects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but honestly the last section comes off as incredibly condescending; there's a better way to express the sentiment that Google Scholar is a good resource.

Comment: @Not_Here I'm really sorry; that wasn't my intention at all. Does it look nicer now?